# No se guardan los datos del formulario en la base de datos(php pdo y ajax)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, pdo

**Este es mi primer intento de utilizar php pdo con ajax, además no se si esta es la mejor forma  para hacerlo pero resulta que me surgió un problema, que a la hora de insertar los datos del formulario en la base de datos me lanza un "Error al insertar".**

**Este es mi index.php**

**El formulario es para insertar algunos datos como prueba sobre autos, además está dentro de una ventana Modal**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- datatables CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <!--font awesome con CDN-->  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">  
    
    <!-- main css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

    <title>Datatables</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>DATATABLES</h1>
        <!-- Botón de Agregar nuevo registro -->
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary boton" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#agregarRegistro">
        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Nuevo Registro
    </button>
    <!-- tabla de datos -->

      <div id="tablaDatos"></div>

    <!-- fin tabla de datos  -->
    </div>
    
    <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="agregarRegistro" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="agregarRegistro" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Agregar Nuevo Registro</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="formInsert" onsubmit="return insertarDatos()" method="POST">
                        <div class="form-row">
                          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label>Marca</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="marcaInsert" id="marcaInsert">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label>Modelo</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="modeloInsert" id="modeloInsert">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Año</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" name="añoInsert" id="añoInsert">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Color</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="colorInsert" id="colorInsert">
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label>Matrícula</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="matriculaInsert" id="matriculaInsert">
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                <label>Precio ($)</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="precioInsert" id="precioInsert">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-primary">
          
               </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-times"></i>&nbsp;Cerrar</button>
                
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- fin ventana modal -->
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <script src="js/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script>
          mostrar();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Esta es mi clase Crud.php y el método de insert**

```
<?php
    require_once 'Conexion.php';

    class Crud extends Conexion{
     
         public static function insertarDatos($datos){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO autos(marca, modelo, año, color, matricula, precio) VALUES (:marca, :modelo, :año, :color, :matricula, :precio)";
            $query = Conexion::conectar()->prepare($sql);
            $query->bindParam(":marca", $datos['marcaInsert'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(":modelo", $datos['modeloInsert'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(":año", $datos['añoInsert'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $query->bindParam(":color", $datos['colorInsert'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(":matricula", $datos['matriculaInsert'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->bindParam(":precio", $datos['precioInsert'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
            return $query->execute();
        }
    }?>
```

**Este es mi archivo insertarDatos.php**

```
<?php
    require_once '../crud/Crud.php';
    
    $datos = array(
        'marcaInsert' => $_POST['marcaInsert'],
        'modeloInsert' => $_POST['modeloInsert'],
        'añoInsert' => $_POST['añoInsert'],
        'colorInsert' => $_POST['colorInsert'],
        'matriculaInsert' => $_POST['matriculaInsert'],
        'precioInsert' => $_POST['precioInsert'],
    
    );

    echo Crud::insertarDatos($datos);


?>
```

**Y este es mi archivo main.js**

```
/* Inicializar el Datatable y cambiar el idioma al español*/

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        "language":{
            "url": "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.21/i18n/Spanish.json"
    }
    });
} );

/* Funciones del CRUD */

/* mostrar datos */

    function mostrar(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"procesos/mostrarDatos.php",
            success:function(r){
                $("#tablaDatos").html(r);
            }
        });
    }

/* fin mostrar datos */

/* insertar datos */

    function insertarDatos(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"procesos/insertarDatos.php",
            data:$('#formInsert').serialize(),
            success:function(r){
                if(r==1){
                    $('#formInsert')[0].reset();
                    mostrar();
                    swal("¡Agregado con éxito!", "", "success");
                }else{
                    swal("¡Error al insertar!", "", "error");
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
/* fin insertar datos */
```

**Agradezco si logran solucionar mi problema**

Comment: Ummm y como se ve el archivo `Conexion.php` del que extiende la clase `Crud`?, ese no lo pusiste, quiza la conexion este fallando, aunque aun no estoy seguro ya que apenas estoy revisando un poco mas a fondo todo.

Comment: Por cierto deberias evitar el uso de caracteres especiales como la `ñ` o tildes para los parametros de tu PDO, pues puede haber un conflicto con estos caracteres, trata de usar solo caracteres que esten dentro del ingles nativamente.

Comment: Por cierto, no se si afecte el hecho de que la tabla autos esta completamente pegada de un parentesis de cierre `)`, puede ser un error estupido pero quiza ese sea el problema debes intentar separar el nombre de la tabla del parentesis de cierre `autos (...)`, o a lo mejor la cantidad de campos o su nombre no coincide, o no coinciden en tipos, aunque dudo que sean los tipos, pero pues no he visto tu tabla como para saber si los tipos coinciden.

Comment: Otra cosa peculiar que veo es que estas intentando usar **ajax con el submit de un form**, se supone que ajax esta diseñado para obtener informacion sin tener que recargar la pagina o redirigirte a otra parte, mi sospecha mas grande es ahora la siguiente: **El problema es que la funcion submit se ejecuta justo cuando la pagina ya esta siendo descargada para enviar la informacion** por lo tanto tu funcion `insertarDatos` no se esta ejecutando debido a que la pagina ya se ha descargado (unloaded). no le da tiempo a la funcion a ejecutarse y simplemente te redirige.

Comment: Posdata: el `return false` **no previene que el formulario te redireccione al hacer submit**.

Comment: Gracias por los comentarios, la conexión está bien porque me lista todos los registros sin ningún error

Comment: Una forma de solucionar eso sería cambiar el input type= submit por un type=button?

Comment: Vaya... justo te iba a recomendar eso, me leiste la mente!, sip, deberias hacer eso, aparte tambien deberias cambiar el `this` en JS por el `form`, de esa manera estaras usando puramente `ajax` para el envio y **NO** el submit del form. lo del `this` lo digo porque ahora ya no estarias apuntando directamente al form si no al button.

Comment: Ok voy a intentarlo, gracias

Comment: El problema era con la "ñ"

Comment: Me alegra que te haya funcionado, supongo podemos dar por concluida la pregunta...

Comment: Si, gracias por la ayuda